# How to change the format of substitution variables in a template

Tags: unix, sed, text-files

I need to to iterate over the files in a directory and perform the following replacement.

**Before:**

> Hello ${USER_NAME}, you live at
>   ${HOME_ADDRESS}. It is now ${TIME}

**After:**

> Hello ${userName}, you live at
>   ${homeAddress}. It is now ${time}

The number of different tokens that appear within ${} is large, so it's not really feasible to run:

```
find . -name '*' -exec sed -i 's/${USER_NAME}/${userName}/g' {} \;
find . -name '*' -exec sed -i 's/${TIME}/${time}/g' {} \;
```

etc.

I'm hoping it's possible to perform this replacement using a single command, that looks something like:

```
find . -name '*' -exec sed 's/XXX/YYY/g' {} \;
```

But I can't figure out what to substitute for XXX and YYY. Is it possible to do this in a single command?

Cheers,
Donal

Comment: If execution time is a big constraint, consider using gawk or perl or python as they byte compile at the start to speed up execution. I'm not at all certain that sed does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-i` flag to sed will edit a file in-place. For XXX and YYY, you would use something like:

```
sed -i 's/USER_NAME/userName/g'
```

and so on.

Update: I see that your question was really about changing "USER_NAME" into "userName" automatically. You could try this Perl script:

```
sub convert {
    my $r = lc $_[0];
    $r =~ s/_(.)/\U$1\E/g;
    return $r;
}
while (<>) {
    s/\${([A-Z_]+)}/\${@{[convert $1]}}/g;
    print;
}
```

Run it like this:

```
perl -i convert.pl inputfile.txt
```

Sample output:

```
$ cat inputfile.txt
Hello ${USER_NAME}, you live at ${HOME_ADDRESS}. It is now ${TIME}
$ perl -i convert.pl inputfile.txt
$ cat inputfile.txt
Hello ${userName}, you live at ${homeAddress}. It is now ${time}
```

Comment: I get the following error: "Can't do inplace edit without backup at convert.pl line 6"

However, if I remove the "-i" flag, it seems to work, so I guess I'll just redirect the output, then rename the files. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're on Windows: -i won't work without a backup extension.  Use -i.bak, that'll rename foo to foo.bak before overwriting foo.

Comment: Thanks, I also discovered that the script above incorrectly renamed ${FOO_IMG_SRC} to ${fooImg_src}

Comment: Don: add a 'g' on the second line of the convert function. I have amended the above answer.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I unaccepted the answer just because of this bug, but I'll reaccept it now

Answer (score 4):

Formatted for clarity:

```
sed -i '/^Hello/ { s/\$\{USER_NAME\}/\$\{userName\}/g 
                   s/\$\{HOME_ADDRESS\}/\$\{homeAddress\}/g 
                   s/\$\{TIME\}/\$\{time\}/g
                  }'
```

Where `/^Hello/` identifies the lines you wish to act on (make it more specific if needed) and the rest substitutes each variable name.

---

If writing this into a script consider the use of a HERE document to keep the formatting and make it easier to read and update...

Comment: If I want to apply the replacement to all lines, presumably I just omit '/^Hello/' ?

Comment: Yup. And you can use two addresses there "/^Hello/ /Goodbye$/ {...}" to work and all lines between Hello and goodbye (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works really well.  For completeness, I might add that you can do:

```
sed '/^Hello/ { s/\$\{USER_NAME\}/\$\{userName\}/g' <filename> \
   | sed 's/\$\{HOME_ADDRESS\}/\$\{homeAddress\}/g' \
   | sed 's/\$\{TIME\}/\$\{time\}/g'
```

They're functionally identical (except that mine dumps to stdout;  you'll have to put it somewhere (but you get to keep the original in case, like e, you mess up regularly on your regexps).  I like my formulation just because I can start with the one sed command, then add on more with

```
!! | sed 'yet-enother-regexp'
```

Arrow keys?  vi-mode?  Who needs that stuff? :)